# can't save Google maps marker objects to array in hidden html field

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, json, google-maps-api-3

I followed the example [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/marker-remove)  to create an array of the markers that I put on my Google map on my web page.

I've looked for the past few hours at a lot of example both on the open web and here on SO and nothing I've tried works.

I need to:

1) save a Javascript array of Google Maps marker objects in a hidden input field

2) then retrieve the 'value' of the hidden input field and convert that back to the array of Marker objects so that I can remove these markers from the map

Here's my code, some is based on the Google Maps sample above:

```
 theMarkersArray = new Array();
 for(var i = 0; i < 5; i++)
 {
    marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: myLatLng,
      map: map,
      icon: image,
      shape: shape,
      title: "aMarker",
      zIndex: 1000});

      theMarkersArray.push(marker);
 }

 theMarkersArrayField = document.getElementById('markersArray');

 // I'm using Firefox v28.0, the following line of code halts code executing,
 // I'm thinking that 'JSON.stringify()' is not defined for FF 28.0..?)

 //theMarkersArrayField.value = JSON.stringify(theMarkersArray); 

   // this executes, but I don't think it's saving the array of Marker objects 
   // correctly     
 theMarkersArrayField.value = theMarkersArray;

 alert("the theMarkersArray is: "+ theMarkersArray);
```

When I display the contents of theMarkersArrayField.value using alert(), it looks like this:

```
   [object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object]
```

and when I try to convert theMarkersArrayField.value  back into a Javascript array using either eval() or JSON.parse(),  both fail.

```
 var theMarkersArrayField = document.getElementById('markersArray');

     // DOES NOT WORK
 //var theMarkersArray = JSON.parse(theMarkersArrayField.value);

       // THIS doesn't work either
 //var theMarkersArray = eval(theMarkersArrayField.value);


    // IS NOT AN ARRAY OF 'Marker' objects, just a text string it seems...?
 var theMarkersArray = document.getElementById('markersArray').value;

    // RETURNS '79' INSTEAD OF 5 (only 5 markers were stored in the array, not 79) --
    // 79 is the count of characters in:
 // [object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object] 
 var numMarkers = theMarkersArray.length;
```

I need to store an array of Marker objects in an array then save that array in a hidden field on the page, then later retrieve that from the hidden field, convert it back to an array of Marker objects -- what am I missing?

Comment: (I responded to a question then the questioner deleted his question and I see no 'Delete' option for my original response, thus this.)

Comment: see the updated code with demo...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> - **demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/drA5k/

```
        function addMarker(location) {
        for(var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: location,
                map: map
            });
            // of course if you need only the position you can avoid looping and just get 
            // marker.position.k and marker.position.A , this example dimostrate 
            // how to iterate and get data from the object and build a custom array...
            for (var o in marker) {
                if (typeof marker[o] === 'object') {
                    if (o === 'position') {
                        var position = marker[o];
                        markers.push({'k' : position.k, 'A' : position.A});
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        document.getElementById('markersArray').value = JSON.stringify(markers);
        }
```

Comment: Thank you, +1, I was trying to avoid keeping a global array (although that's what the Google sample code seems to do), and was hoping to find out what exactly my code is doing wrong.

Comment: JSON.stringify can't hande that marker object it produce the following  error Converting circular structure to JSON. also you can't put an object inside an input element. you can try to loop it extrat the sensitive data and build an array like [val_1, val_2, etc]

Answer (score 1):

I create a store locator with this code

```
   myData = JSON = $.parseJSON(msg);

                var dist = [];//Array to hold distances


                              var geocoder =  new google.maps.Geocoder();
                                    geocoder.geocode( { 'address': ''+origin2+', us'}, function(results, status) {
                                          if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {

                                        myLatitud = results[0].geometry.location.lat();
                                        myLongitud = results[0].geometry.location.lng();

                                        origin1 = new google.maps.LatLng(myLatitud, myLongitud);

                                         for (var i = 0; i < myData.length; i++){
                                        var point = new google.maps.LatLng(myData[i].latitud,myData[i].longitud);
                                        var distance = (google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeDistanceBetween(origin1, point)/1000).toFixed(2);
                                        dist.push(distance);
                                       }  


                                   var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), {
                                      zoom: 11,
                                      center: new google.maps.LatLng(myLatitud, myLongitud),
                                      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
                                    });



                                  var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

                                  var marker;

                                   marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                                        position: new google.maps.LatLng(myLatitud, myLongitud),//25.7889689 -80.22643929999998 
                                        //position: new google.maps.LatLng(25.7889689,-80.22643929999998),
                                        map: map,
                                        icon : originIcon
                                     });

                                   google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
                                                    return function() {
                                                      // infowindow.setContent(myData[i].store);
                                                      //infowindow.open(map, marker);
                                                        map.setZoom(10);
                                                      map.setCenter(marker.getPosition());
                                                    }
                                                  })(marker, i));



                                    map.setCenter(marker.getPosition());  
                                    map.setZoom(10);

                                    millas = params['millas'];

                                    var result = [];//Array of definitive stores

                                    for ( var i = 0; i < dist.length; i++) {

                                        var kilometro = dist[i];
                                        if (millas == "1" && kilometro < 8) {

                                             marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                                                position: new google.maps.LatLng(myData[i].latitud, myData[i].longitud),
                                                map: map,
                                                 icon : destinationIcon
                                             });

                                              google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
                                                    return function() {
                                                      infowindow.setContent(myData[i].store);
                                                      infowindow.open(map, marker);
                                                      map.setZoom(12);
                                                      map.setCenter(marker.getPosition());

                                                    }
                                                  })(marker, i));

                                        }
```

Comment: Thank you, I'm still too new to this, you're more advanced than I am, thank you for your suggestion.